# Running yarn from mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, yarnpkg

I had problems running yarn in my visual studio code, every time I try to run the command I get this error:

```
zsh: command not found: yarn visual studio code
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems running yarn:

```
zsh: command not found: yarn visual studio code
```

I solved the issue running the alternative command that was suggested in the official documentation:
`curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`

You can check the documentation here:
[Official documentation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#mac-stable)